# Creating an asynchronous controller that returns OK immediately

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to wrap my head around the new async/await functionality in combination with webapi.

What I would like to do is the following:

- I'm receiving a (POST) request on a controller (A) on a certain endpoint.
- This controller does nothing but just sends this request through to a second controller (B) on another endpoint (don't ask me why - just a thought experiment).
- Let's say B does some long-running work (retrieve data from somewhere) and stores the result in the database.

I don't want to wait on the work from B before I can return a OK message to the request that was sent to A. I would like to be able to call A and get OK back ASAP while the work is still being completed on B.

Is this even possible? If so, what would be a correct way to design something like this?

Thanks for any pointers you might give me.

Comment: What happens in case B fails to insert to the database? Does that interest the caller?

Comment: Nope, don't care what happens in B.

Comment: Upvotes for everyone because I learned something from each remark. Thanks guys - the remark that async - await is only useful in situations that you have to respond on the result of the long running task was useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is to trigger a "Fire and Forget" semantics on your call.

If you're using .NET 4.5.2, you can use `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` to register and queue work on a ASP.NET Threadpool thread.

If you're on previous versions, you can use [`BackgroundTaskManager`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AspNetBackgroundTasks) by Stephan Cleary.

Note this has nothing to do with `async-await`.

An example would look like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Foo()
{
    HostingEnvironment.QueueUserWorkItem(() => { /* offloaded code here */ });
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to respond to the caller with a [response code of 202 (accepted)](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html) to indicate to the client that some other processing is ongoing.
Then if your client needs additional feedback it could do a long poll, or you could implement a websocket, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just an assumptioin based out of the async/await concept explained by John Skeet. The async/await pattern uses continuations which maintain the state machine. Basically the frame work is supposed to execute the instructions till the end of the synchronous methods.

When it encounters the async call instructions, it invokes it and if the result is readily available goes to the next steps and does the processing. If it does not have the result immediately after the call, it returns back from the method leaving this to be taken care by the framework. So in your case, I think practically it would return immediately if you have no code. But if you have any long running code, it should return leaving the job to the background framework thread but result may come back later.

If your objective is to make sure you don't block the foreground, then this will be achieved with the first controller itself. But even in your case, the second controller wouldn't block the UI. To your question on whether this is right or wrong, I am sure because you may have some reasons why you are thinking of such a pattern.

There are numerous experts here. Correct me if my interpretation is wrong, please:)

Answer (score 1):

You start the background work and respond immediately. The async pattern is only to be used in case you have to respond in any way on the result of the long running task and prevent blocking of the calling thread.
i.e:

```
public bool ControllerAMethod(byte[] somedata)
{
  Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
  {
    ControllerB.SendData(somedata);
  });
  return true;
}
```

Comment: [This is dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html) in ASP.NET.